# I'm creating a filterable lightbox gallery. Filters/buttons work for the lightbox, but the buttons do not change the images on the site itself

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to create a gallery with selectable buttons that will change the images that also filter the lightbox gallery once a filter is selected.

The lightbox filter works once each button is selected displaying the correct images from each filter, but the buttons do not change the images on the site itself.

Here is the site for reference: http://www.barbarabielpainting.com/new/

Apologies for the mess, it's not completely styled yet.

I'm not very familiar with JS, but I've looked through the files and to me the references appear to be correct. I believe the issue may be with the on onclick="call(this.id) or the JS itself.

```
  <div class="tz-gallery">
        <div class="buttoncenter">
        <div class="buttoncontainer" id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="filter-button btn-default" id="all" onclick="call(this.id)">Show all</button>
  <button class="filter-button btn-default" id="series1" onclick="call(this.id)">Series 1</button>
  <button class="filter-button btn-default" id="series2" onclick="call(this.id)">Series 2</button>
  <button class="filter-button btn-default" id="series3"  onclick="call(this.id)">Series 3</button>
</div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 show column series1">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series1" href="img/paintings/1.jpg">
                        <img src="img/paintings/1.jpg" alt="Park">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 show column series2">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series2" href="img/paintings/2.jpg">
                        <img src="img/paintings/2.jpg" alt="Bridge">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 show column series3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series3" href="img/paintings/3.jpg">
                        <img src="img/paintings/3.jpg" alt="Tunnel">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 show column series1">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series1" href="img/paintings/1.jpg">
                        <img src="img/paintings/1.jpg" alt="Coast">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 show column series2">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series2" href="img/paintings/2.jpg">
                        <img src="img/paintings/2.jpg" alt="Rails">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 show column series3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series3" href="img/paintings/3.jpg">
                        <img src="img/paintings/3.jpg" alt="Traffic">
                    </a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


    <!-- ======== Java Script ======== -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.8.1/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
    <script src="js/plugins/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4.1.3 -->
    <script src="js/plugins/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Slick Slider -->
    <script src="js/plugins/slick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Couner Up-->
    <script src="js/plugins/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Wow JS -->
    <script src="js/plugins/wow.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Magnific Popup-->
    <script src="js/plugins/magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Main Js-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

```
var lightboxDescription = GLightbox({
  selector: 'glightbox'
});


function call(id) {
  const items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("filter"));
  items.map(function (item, index) {
    console.log(item);
    if (id === "all") {
      item.classList.remove('d-none');
      item.classList.add('fadeIn','glightbox');
      setTimeout(clean,500);
    } else {
      const check = items[index].classList.contains(id);
      console.log(check);

      if (check) {
        item.classList.remove('d-none');
        item.classList.add('fadeIn','glightbox');
      } else {
        item.classList.add('d-none');
        item.classList.remove('fadeIn','glightbox');
      }
    }
  })
}

function clean() {
  const items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("filter"));
  items.map(function (item, index) {
    item.classList.remove('fadeIn');
  })
}
```

```
.gallery_product
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
            animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.filter-button
{
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #42B32F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #42B32F;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.filter-button:hover
{
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #42B32F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #42B32F;

}
.filter-button.active
{
    background-color: #42B32F;
    color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
.fadeIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

The result I want is a filterable lightbox gallery that displays correct images on the site once each filter is selected, as well as once the images are enlarged in the lightbox.

The current result is only displaying the filtered images once the images are enlarged in lightbox, but the filters do not change the images on the site itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are no hiding the elements from the list, you can accomplish that with something like (I only change some parts, you still need your current call method, but replace the call in the onclick), I removed the show class:
html:

```
<div class="tz-gallery">
  <div class="buttoncenter">
    <div class="buttoncontainer" id="myBtnContainer">
      <button class="filter-button btn-default" id="all" onclick="callEnhanced(this.id)">Show all</button>
      <button class="filter-button btn-default" id="series1" onclick="callEnhanced(this.id)">Series 1</button>
      <button class="filter-button btn-default" id="series2" onclick="callEnhanced(this.id)">Series 2</button>
      <button class="filter-button btn-default" id="series3" onclick="callEnhanced(this.id)">Series 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 column series1 filter2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series1" href="img/paintings/1.jpg">
          <img src="img/paintings/1.jpg" alt="Park">
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 column show series2 filter2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series2" href="img/paintings/2.jpg">
          <img src="img/paintings/2.jpg" alt="Bridge">
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 column show series3 filter2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series3" href="img/paintings/3.jpg">
          <img src="img/paintings/3.jpg" alt="Tunnel">
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 column show series1 filter2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series1" href="img/paintings/1.jpg">
          <img src="img/paintings/1.jpg" alt="Coast">
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 column show series2 filter2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series2" href="img/paintings/2.jpg">
          <img src="img/paintings/2.jpg" alt="Rails">
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 column show series3 filter2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a class="glightbox gallery_product filter filter-button series3" href="img/paintings/3.jpg">
          <img src="img/paintings/3.jpg" alt="Traffic">
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function callEnhanced(id) {
  call(id); // Here we call your current call method
  const items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("filter2")); // here we filter)
  items.map(function (item, index) {
    if (id === "all") {
      item.classList.add('show');
    } else {
      var check = items[index].classList.contains(id);
      if (check) {
        item.classList.add('show');
      } else {
        item.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your response. I'm getting a parsing error in js after making your changes:

ERROR: Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved const items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("filter2")); // here we filter)

I also updated the site based on your changes so you can see if I made an error.

Comment: I was seeing your webpage, you need to remove the show class, the const is good, I edit the aswer

Comment: @SeanDraper please use the edited callEnhanced, I used that one in your page and seems that works

Comment: Updating to the edited callEnhanced function worked! Thanks for all your help.